# What is the Christian view on Breatharianism?

Tags: comparative-religion

What is the Christian view on Breatharianism? I see a from of denying the flesh, and a couple verses popped in my head while learning about this.

> Therefore I say to you, do not worry about your life, what you will eat or what you will drink; nor about your body, what you will put on. Is not life more than food and the body more than clothing? (Matthew 6:25 NKJV)
>
> In the meantime His disciples urged Him, saying, “Rabbi, eat.” But He said to them, “I have food to eat of which you do not know.” Therefore the disciples said to one another, “Has anyone brought Him anything to eat?” Jesus said to them, “My food is to do the will of Him who sent Me, and to finish His work. Do you not say, ‘There are still four months and then comes the harvest’? Behold, I say to you, lift up your eyes and look at the fields, for they are already white for harvest! And he who reaps receives wages, and gathers fruit for eternal life, that both he who sows and he who reaps may rejoice together. For in this the saying is true: ‘One sows and another reaps.’ I sent you to reap that for which you have not labored; others have labored, and you have entered into their labors.” (John 4:31-38 NKJV)
>
> And when He had fasted forty days and forty nights, afterward He was hungry. (Matthew 4:2 NKJV)
>
> for I say to you, I will no longer eat of it until it is fulfilled in the kingdom of God. (Luke 22:16 NKJV)

**Then on the other side I see:**

> The Son of Man came eating and drinking, and they say, ‘Look, a glutton and a winebibber, a friend of tax collectors and sinners!’ But wisdom is justified by her children.” (Matthew 11:19 NKJV)

Answer (score 2):

> James 2:15-16 "If a brother or sister be naked, and destitute of daily food, and one of you say unto them, Depart in peace, be ye warmed and filled; notwithstanding ye give them not those things which are needful to the body; what doth it profit?"

If people don't need food, why even say "be filled"? And why would he describe food as "needful to the body"?   So the Bible clearly teaches that food is necessary for survival.

Comment: You answered but did you cast your vote for the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Christians, like [most people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inedia#Scientific_basis), believe those who claim to live without food and water are frauds.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Breatharianism but just read the wikipedia article.

To answer your question, Christians are opposed to it by definition.

> Breatharians claim that food and possibly water are not necessary, and that humans can be sustained solely by prana (the vital life force in Hinduism).

Incidentally, fasting in Christianity has historically been very important. In the Orthodox and Catholic tradition, fasting is a mechanism by which one becomes closer to God -- prayer is more effective, worship is more effective, sinful thoughts are reduced, and the proclivity to engage in active sin is also reduced.

The Orthodox laymen do not eat any food during the first three days of Lent. Monks on the other hand go much longer than that, some rumored to go all 40 days.

Comment: I appreciate your dedication. Even in some lies I find truth, this is why I investigate, yet in the end only the truth will stand.